# Can you simply remove a shorting decoupling capacitor without replacing it?

Tags: capacitor, digital-logic, decoupling-capacitor, bypass-capacitor

In a digital system, not RF related. If there are numerous filter caps on the same power rail but only one fails shorted, can you just remove without replacing since the others will remain in circuit?

I’ve seen people do it and the devices seem to work normal after but I’ve always wondered if long term it can cause any issues?

Comment: It is like there are a bunch of cars going over bumpy road and one car blows it's shock absorbers. The tires now make more noise. Will it still run or will something else breakdown? CMOS logic switches a small internal shock of current each time and the Caps help smoothen the current locally.  If not excessive OK, if marginal, a glitch make cause the power window to go up randomly.

Comment: It’ll run until something else is affected by it down the road?

Comment: @Tony, that's kind of stretched analogy and clarity beyond a limit :-)

Comment: Yes . In truth a good design will have lots of margin but each cap contributing to reduce EMI and the probability of miscommunication from edges on logic levels for a group or in some cases for each IC.  The impedance of each capacitor contributes to lower the spectrum of some localized impulse.  The real answer is much more complex in time or frequency.

Comment: By "filter caps," are you referring to the capacitors which are right next to the ICs?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I’m referring mainly to caps on a vcc line where there are numerous caps placed close to the circuit that uses vcc for power or switching (bucking/boosting)

Comment: Manufactures do not just 'add' capacitors willy-nilly. Each ones serves a purpose, even if it is localized filtering of resonate waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your power plane has 50 decoupling caps, and you remove one, and there are others nearby, the consequences should be small.

It's probabilistic: the manufacturer put in enough caps so the board will work across process and temperature variations. Some batches of chips may be more sensitive to noise than others, logic level thresholds may vary a bit, and this also depends on temperature, capacitor tolerance, etc.

For example if you got lucky and your fifty +/-20% caps are all +10% or above, then removing one still gives capacitance above spec.

However, maybe the cap was used near some vias to allow the return current of a high speed signal to change reference planes, for example. If it is removed, then the board will radiate more, as the return current will have to find another (longer) path. It will probably still work fine, but will no longer meet EMI spec.

Answer (score 0):

With the high volume of some consumer devices, that cost of a single cap can start to matter.

So if one could get away with a cap less, it would not be present in the first place. Sure the device works fine for now, but it might misbehave anytime.

Maybe an IC burns out sooner, maybe you get random glitches, maybe you get poorer performance, like pixel errors or less sound quality (depending what kind of device we are talking about here).

Worst case you start to emit radio waves and someday the Bundesnetzagentur knocks down your door and confiscates all your electronics (you live in Germany, don't you?)

Answer (score 0):

I would replace it but think of it this way:

Did it blow because it was statistically end-of-life or did it blow because it was the one which had to do more work then the others. This capacitor may have been exposed to higher current spikes then the others. So this one may be more important then the others.